# What are the content and functional words?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Now, I start studying English as a foreign language. I wonder that what are the content and functional words? Are they the same as parts of speech?

Comment: See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326703/content-word-and-function-word. Possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They group the parts-of-speech into two classes:

Content words are an open class meaning that new words can be coined (nouns, adjectives, verbs, and adverbs formed from adjectives).  They represent things that could be experienced.

Function words are a closed class meaning it is very difficult to create any new ones (conjunctions, prepositions, determiners, pronouns, and pro-form adverbs).  They represent abstract relationships between things.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Your information is very useful for me.